# Extract a key from a Base64 decoded string

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to decode a base 64 format string in JMeter, with a BeanSheel PostProcessor, and extract the `nameid` from the string, which (nameid) I am further going to use in sending another request.

I tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

String decoded_response = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(data));
String memberId = decoded_response.nameid;
log.info("memberid", memberId)
```

It is giving me errors as:

```
ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;  String decoded_response = new St . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Cannot access field: nameid, on object: iÇ²Ïí¢G§{"typ":"JWT","alg":"HS256"}{"nameid":"1862","unique_name":"user1@mywebsite.com","iss":"http://mywebsite-app.azurewebsites.net/","aud":"414e1927a3884f68abc79f7283837fd1","exp":1635435731,"nbf":1635349331}$S‘­vC‡öRé™v„2xÉr}ïK…u®KŸäpÏÆ¯-¢G§þÜ©y·š­êÞÆ˜«zÏâŸÎ·÷Ö¬rXžžßâvx
```

Basically here I want to decode the token and get some of the id fields to be used in further requests. What is a good way of doing this? Is there any alternative to store the nameid in another variable and use it further in another request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to decode [Base64URL](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4648#section-5), not Base64
2. If it succeeds you will get JSON which needs to be parsed
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting

So I think you need to change your code to something like:

```
def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString()

def parts = response.split('\\.')

def part2 = org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.EncodingGroovyMethods.decodeBase64Url(parts[1])

def nameid = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(part2).nameid
```

More information:

- [EncodingGroovyMethods](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/EncodingGroovyMethods.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)